# Is ASP.Net State Server an elegant solution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, state-server, asp.net-cache

We have an ASP.Net MVC project that will start with a single web server but will likely soon scale into a small web farm.  As ASP.Net Authentication stores a UserID, and data caching may also be useful, we will likely need to make the jump to state server fairly soon.

I'd like to hear from others how State Server has been to work with and how it scales from a performance perspective.

Alternatively, we could architect it as completely stateless by not using data caching and tracking sessions with an encrypted cookie.

Update:  I had some misinformation previously (from a Microsoft technical advisor...), Auth does not store in session like I thought, it just stores in the cookie.  So, we would not need state server in this situation afterall.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "data caching"... Do you want to use the state server as a cache? That's not its purpose...

Comment: What would you say its purpose is?  I had a conversation with a Microsoft tech today which led me to believe it may be needed to handle authentication, but after further research today I think that may not be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fully stateless (sessionless) application would be more scalable. Using [ASP.NET FormsAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx), user id is stored in an encrypted cookie which is available on every request and you can obtain user information from a data store. To further improve performance you could cache the results of some expensive queries. Ideally this cache would be distributed over a cache servers farm. For example youy could use [memcached](http://memcached.org/) which has a [provider for ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/memcached_aspnet.aspx).

Comment: cool--what you said just helped confirm a bunch of research I did today, thanks for the answer.